# Does a bounty stay with a question if it is migrated

Tags: support, bounties, migration

If I put a bounty on a question and it was migrated to another SE site, what would happen to the bounty? Would it stay on the question even though it had been migrated? Or would it just disappear?

Or is it the case that a question cannot be migrated if it still has an activate bounty on it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, a question cannot be migrated if there is currently a bounty on it. This is because questions cannot be closed with a bounty on them, and migration is just a special case of closing as off-topic.

The bounty must first be manually refunded by a moderator before the question can be migrated.

Reference: [Bounty FAQs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/309993)

Comment: Btw, how did you know that questions with bounty cannot be closed?

Comment: @Pacerier If you'd like an "official" reference, see [the bounty FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/16065/180276).